# Can Schema Validation be turned off in ApacheDS

Tags: apacheds

I need to import an LDIF file from a system that heavily customized their Schema. Is there a way for me to import the file without having to have knowledge of their custom schema?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible in ApacheDS.